# Change file types from rows data to log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, log

I am looking for small advice. My database has 12 log files and x_log11 is showing file type as Rows data instead of Log and file group as primary. I am using SQL 2014.
I need to change it from rows data to log as it is log file?
will there be any impact if I will keep like this.
If I am trying to shrink(for other purpose) log files x_log11 is showing in data files.
will this settings impact on file growth of log files?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to have more than one log file at all? Please read [this](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/multiple-log-files-and-why-theyre-bad/)...

Comment: I don't want.It's already there in my environment. So just trying to understand what can I do in this situation.

Comment: Rather than try to change a data file to a log file (which is not possible), what you should do is remove the 10 additional log files (and possibly rename this one, though that is solely cosmetic).

Comment: I guess you classify your files by the suffix of your database file names. Well, if that's the case, just rename your files.

Answer (score 2):

A Rows file stores data and is where your data and meta-data lives.
A Log file stores changes to that data.

You can't change one to the other.

Comment: But my log file 11 is in rows data rather than log. can't change this? will it impact on growth of log files.

Comment: You can change the NAME of the file, but not the TYPE (rows vs logs) of file.

Comment: In theory, you can REMOVE a file, and create a new one that has the same name and is the other type. But removing ROW files means you're going to lose data. And removing LOG files may risk your system as well, unless you do so carefully.